# Limit Total Results with Pagination

Tags: channel-entries, pagination

Easy question. How do I set a limit on the *total* results for a page that has pagination?  I have a site that displays 16 entries per-page, but would like to limit the total results to 200.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty easy to do using [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash).

First, make a list of the 200 entries you want to be shown in pages. This line should have no white-space or line returns in it to prevent parsing errors.

```
{exp:stash:set name="entry_ids" parse_tags="yes"}{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" limit="200" disable="categories|category_fields|custom_fields|member_data|pagination" dynamic="off"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}{/exp:stash:set}
```

Then load the entries for each 16 entry page as normal:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{exp:stash:get name='entry_ids' backspace='1'}" 
    parse="inward" paginate="bottom" limit="16" dynamic="off"}
    {title}<br/>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: +1 for this approach. Might be worth adding that you could disable custom fields for the first `{exp:channel:entries}` tag for a significant performance boost, as you only need the `entry_id`s.

Comment: Good suggestion Tom. I added a full disable parameter since none of the optional parts are actually needed.

Comment: You can even add `trim="yes"` to the `{exp:stash:set}` tag which will remove whitespace and allow you to format your code better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on how to "cap" it at 200, but you could always wrap the `{paginate}` contents with a conditional to only show to a certain point (ie. 200/16 = 12.5 pages).

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="name"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks"
    limit="16"
}
...
{paginate}
{if {current_page} < 13}
  {first_page}
          <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
  {/first_page}

  {previous_page}
          <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
  {/previous_page}

  {next_page}
          <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
  {/next_page}

  {last_page}
          <li><a href="url/P192" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
  {/last_page}
{/if}
{/paginate} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You may need to tweak the `{last_page}` hard coded url.